# Solving this two variable limit

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I have problems figuring out this limit I found online:

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (1,2)} \frac{2x-y}{\sqrt{3x-y} - \sqrt{5y-9x}}$$

So I get that this is a basic limit but since I am new to this, I'd appreciate help.

I tried making a substitution $y=kx$, but since $x$ and $y$ approach 1 and 2 respectively, do I need to add anything to the right side of $y=kx$?

Polar coordinates don't seem to help, and I tried multiplying by the conjugate of the denominator but I don't think it was fruitful.

Help appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What about multiply your expression by $\frac{\sqrt{3x-y}+\sqrt{5y-9x}}{\sqrt{3x-y}+\sqrt{5y-9x}}$ ?

Comment: As I mentioned I tried multiplying by that expression but I still don't get anywhere. I get an indeterminate form "0/0", and regarding substitutions I can't seem to figure out how to do them because x and y are not approaching 0,0  , but different points on their respective axes.

Comment: Then you should try again ;-)

Comment: @Surb Thank you, got it !